# R: Cannot Read All Worksheets in Excel

Tags: r, excel, readxl

See below `readxl::readxl_example()` that I am attempting to copy:

```
path <- readxl::readxl_example("datasets.xls")
lapply(readxl::excel_sheets(path), readxl::read_excel, path=path)
```

The above obviously works, and I'm essentially trying to recreate for my own work, below:

```
df2016<- readxl::read_excel("data_2016.xlsx")
lapply(readxl::excel_sheets(df2016), readxl::read_excel, df2016= df2016)
```

When I run my code, I return the below error: 
    Error: `path` must be a string

Comment: `readxl::readxl_example` just returns a path to a file provided in the `readxl` package. Replace `df2016` with the path to your excel file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reading the excel, provide the location in the lapply function. For example:

```
location <- "D:/data_2016.xlsx"
lapply(readxl::excel_sheets(location), readxl::read_excel, path=location)
```